# Bounding integral arising from expectation of a random variable satisfying Bernstein's inequality

Tags: pr.probability, st.statistics

Let $X$ be a random variable s.t. for $v, b > 0$ and $C \geq 1$:

$$ P(X \geq t) \leq C\exp\left(-\frac{t^2}{2(v^2 + bt)} \right) $$

I am trying to show that $\mathbb{E}X \leq 2v(\sqrt{\pi} + \sqrt{\log C}) + 4b(1 + \log C)$.

In terms of progress I have made so far, I set $X = \int_0^\infty P(X \geq t)dt$, and have also made cases for when $v^2 > bt$ and otherwise (i.e. simplifying the exponentiated value to be $-t^2/4v^2$ in one case and $-t^2/4bt$ in the other).

This obtainis all the non $C$ values in the final inequality; However, I can't figure out how to squash the $C$ into the $\log C$ and $\sqrt{\log C}$ terms.

Comment: You have a closing bracket missing in the second equation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For $t>0$, we have $v^2+bt\le\max(2bt,2v^2)$, whence 
\begin{equation}
 P(X\ge t)\le1\wedge\max[Q_1(t),Q_2(t)]\le[1\wedge Q_1(t)]+[1\wedge Q_2(t)], 
\end{equation}
where $x\wedge y:=\min(x,y)$, 
\begin{equation}
Q_1(t):=C\exp\Big(-\frac{t^2}{4bt}\Big),\quad 
 Q_2(t):=C\exp\Big(-\frac{t^2}{4v^2}\Big).
\end{equation} So, 
\begin{equation}
 EX=\int_0^\infty P(X\ge t)\,dt\le I_1+I_2,
\end{equation}
where 
\begin{multline}
 I_1:=\int_0^\infty[1\wedge Q_1(t)]\,dt
 =4b\ln C+C\int_{4b\ln C}^\infty \exp\Big(-\frac{t}{4b}\Big)\,dt=4b(1+\ln C)
\end{multline}
and 
\begin{multline}
 I_2:=\int_0^\infty[1\wedge Q_2(t)]\,dt
 =v\sqrt 2\int_0^\infty\min(1,Ce^{-s^2/2})\,ds
\\ 
 =v\sqrt 2\Big(\sqrt{2\ln C}+C\int_{\sqrt{2\ln C}}^\infty e^{-s^2/2}\,ds\Big)
 \le 2v\big(\sqrt{\ln C}+\sqrt\pi/2\big);   
\end{multline} 
the latter inequality follows because $\int_t^\infty e^{-s^2/2}\,ds\le\sqrt{\pi/2}\,e^{-t^2/2}$ for $t\ge0$.

Thus, 
\begin{equation}
 EX\le 4b(1+\ln C)+2v\big(\sqrt{\ln C}+\sqrt\pi/2\big),
\end{equation}
which is a bit better than the bound requested in the OP, where we see $\sqrt\pi$ in place of $\sqrt\pi/2$.

Comment: Thank you! On a more conceptual note, how is it that there is no linear dependence on $C$? I almost convinced myself this is impossible, since the LHS can be written as C*[some constant integral], whereas the right hand side only grows as $log(C)$.

Comment: Since any probability is $\le1$, the tail bound actually available to us is of the form $1\wedge(Cq(t))$, which is nonlinear in $C$, and, in contrast with $Cq(t)$, does not grow with $C$ at all as soon as $C$ becomes large enough. After integration, the resulting bound does grow with $C$, but only logarithmically in $C$, much slower than $C$ itself.